# How to compare child object based on their transform object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm generating a lot of objects via this function:

```
private GameObject CreateGhost(Transform p, float r, float g, float b)
{
    GameObject result = Instantiate(
        gameObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity
    );
    Transform ghost_t = result.transform;
    RectTransform ghost_rt = result.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    ghost_t.SetParent(p, false);
    ghost_rt.anchorMin = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    ghost_rt.anchorMax = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    ghost_rt.pivot = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    ghost_rt.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);

    Image m = result.GetComponent<Image>();
    m.color = new Color(r, g, b, 0.7f);

    return result;
}
```

Knowing that the parameter `Transform p` is always the same, there are a lot of children in the same "parent" object.

When the user clicks on an object, I make it move, and I want to see if its Rect overlaps another rect (NB: I dont want to use `BoxCollider2D` for now).

My loop is like that:

```
RectTransform ghost_rt = Ghost.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
Rect ghost_r = new Rect(ghost_rt.anchoredPosition, 
    new Vector2(ghost_rt.rect.width, ghost_rt.rect.height));
bool overlaps = false;
foreach (Transform child_t in Dst.transform) {
    if (!GameObject.ReferenceEquals(child_t, ghost_rt)) {
        RectTransform rt = child_t.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        Rect cmp_r = new Rect(rt.anchoredPosition,
            new Vector2(rt.rect.width, rt.rect.height));
        DebugText.text += "cmp_r:" + cmp_r + "\n";
        if (cmp_r.Overlaps(ghost_r)) {
            overlaps = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This comparison doesn't work: `(!GameObject.ReferenceEquals(child_t, ghost_rt))`.

I tried that one too without success: `(!GameObject.ReferenceEquals(child_t.parent, ghost_rt.parent))`

What is the method to know if I can compare with the other child (= different from the current object)?

Comment: have you tried comparing `child_t.gameObject` and `ghost_rt.gameObject`?

Comment: ReferenceEquals is for a C# object not for a Unity3d GameObject.You can compare. You need to know if both rectangle have the same position right?

Comment: @Dunno yes, same: it find they're all equal.

Comment: child_t.Overlaps(ghost_rt.rect)

Comment: @joreldraw That's what i've done actually: it's impossible to put the same rectangle at the same position, so if i try to compare to a rectangle that is the same, then I *suppose* it's the same. But it's not good programming. I'm trying to make things better than what I'm forced to do in the Web, I hope Unity won't be bad DIY like we all have to do in the Web.

Comment: your comparing your rect with a recttransform childs. What are you trying to prevent? 2 childs rect with same position?

Comment: @joreldraw Your solution is good may I ask you to give it so I can check it as valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rect.Overlaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Overlaps.html) to know if 1 rect are overlapping other:

child_t.Overlaps(ghost_rt.rect)